# Problem in code in C language: No display when including a specific block of code

Tags: c

> hangman code: line 113-125
>   https://pastebin.com/r1B8rkD1

All are good except when I include this line of code:

```
         //Verify mask if all is filled up.
              int sea;
              gameover=1;
            //  for(sea=0;sea<length;sea++)
              {
                if(!mask[sea])
                    {
                    gameover = 1;
                      break;    
                    }
              }
```

**What could be the problem? It shows no results when I include it on my code. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks**

Comment: initialize `sea`: `int sea = 0;` otherwise `sea` can have any value and when you do `mask[sea]` you may be doing `mask[-42]` and causing UB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point - `if(!mask[sea])`, the variable `sea` is unassigned. You are using the value of  `sea` as an offset for `mask`. This causes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The `for` statement that you commented out starts by assigning the integer `0` to `sea` using the assignment operator `=`. Assuming `mask` is an array, you are using the value of `sea` to jump to a specific element of the array in the `if` statement.

Now, that `sea` is unassigned, it might be anything (even a negative number). Thus, you are trying to access some element in an array using an unknown index. It's like you know which street your friend lives on, but you do not know the house number.

HTH

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? Where should I assign sea to? what do you mean by offset?

Comment: Thank You very much. i just assigned the value of int sea=0; thanks!

Comment: got it. I am just starting to familiarize myself on stackoverflow